# Simple parallax background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple parallax background and I'm trying to use the background position like this:

```
$('#background').css("background-position","100% " + ($(this).scrollTop() / 2) + "px")
```

But when I try to use that, the background image jumps or lags, especially in browsers like IE9. Are there any easy fixes for this, or does anyone have any pointer of other ways to do it?

Comment: use css transitions or jquery animate.

Comment: Try $('#background').stop(true).animate("background-position","100% " + ($(this).scrollTop() / 2) + "px", 50)

Comment: but i want it to be depending on the scoll and if i use animate or transitions it will not fire constantly, right?

Comment: The .stop(true) will prevent animate calls from stacking up.  The animate doesn't really fire more than once, but it will smooth out the movement between the scroll events.

Comment: I don't think the `.animate()` method can be used like that. Only with single numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Background position is pretty bad on performance try translate3d instead.

```
document.getElementById('element').style.transform = 'translate3d(0,' + (window.scrollY/2) + 'px, 0)';
```